# MS Word to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, word

I'd like to take a 2007 MS Word document, and display the information in that document on a 2010 SharePoint library page.  I essentially want to take the information within the Word document and have it displayed the same way on a SP page.

I've tried converting the Word document to XML, but have had no luck.  When I load the document into the SP site, I do not see the drop-down option to "convert document."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save Word file in HTML, open in Notepad to copy and paste into the html source window of a content editor page. If you have images, you'll need to add those separately.